# Two-way databinding to mddialog

Tags: angularjs, two-way-binding, mddialog

I cannot figure out how to make a two-way-binding to an mddialog. Can anyone give me an example, where data passed to a mddialog is updated when it is updated in the original scope?

I have tried parsing data using 'locals' with no avail, setting the dialog scope to the main scope, etc. But I must be doing something wrong.

As an example I expect a mddialog to be open (using $mdDialog.show()). The modal template show a number, that can be increased by one when clicking a button on the dialog template. At the same time, the number is also outside the modal (parent), with another button that can decrease the number when clicked. The number is updated in both places when either button is clicked.